# Multiselect picklist and owner id validation

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning, soql, custom-object

An administrator uploads the data in the custom object, By giving the ownerid and the multiselect picklist values. Each owner can be assigned each multiselect picklist value only ones.
Example : A record is inserted with ownerid 'xxxxx' and multiselect picklist values 'A';'B' Another record should not be allowed to be inserted with the same ownerid and same multiselect picklist values 'A' or 'B', but can be inserted with different multiselect picklist values.
The new record can be inserted with the same A,B values if the owner id is different.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this just by using Salesforce administration would be the following one:

1. Create a new text field and set it as **unique**
2. Create a Flow and update the field that you just created with something like (OwnerId + Multipicklist Value)

By doing this, you ensure that you can't have in the System two records with the same Owner Id and same values for your Multipicklist.

You can also use a Duplicate Rule with some Matching Rule to achieve the same (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_rules_create.htm&type=5).

Obviously, a different approach would be to create a **before trigger** for the Custom Object and perform the validation from Apex to prevent duplication.